How can I remove this error "cannot determine truth value of Relational"
Here is the source code created in python (anaconda):
# STABILITY OF THE SYSTEMS OF EQUATIONS
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, diff, Matrix, I

# Define symbols
u, v, alpha, beta, mu, omega, gamma = symbols('u v alpha beta mu omega gamma')
real=True
# Define the equations
equation1 = u*(1 - u)*(u - alpha) - (beta*u*v)/(1 + mu*u)
equation2 = (omega*u*v)/(1 + mu*u) - gamma*v


# Find equilibrium points
equilibrium_points = solve([Eq(equation1, 0), Eq(equation2, 0)], (u, v))
print(f"\nEquilibrium Points {equilibrium_points}:")

# Stability analysis
for point in equilibrium_points:
    # Define Jacobian matrix
    J = Matrix([[diff(equation1, u), diff(equation1, v)], [diff(equation2, u), diff(equation2, v)]])
    print(f"\nJacobian {J}:")
    
    # Substitute equilibrium point into the Jacobian matrix
    J_at_point = J.subs({u: point[0], v: point[1]})
    print(f"\nJacobian Matrix at the equilibrium point:\n{J_at_point}")
    
    # Calculate eigenvalues
    eigenvalues = J_at_point.eigenvals()
    print(f"\nEigen values are:\n{eigenvalues}")
    
    # Check the stability
    real_parts = [re.evalf() for re in [eig.as_real_imag()[0] for eig in eigenvalues]]
    print(f"\nReal Parts: {real_parts}")
    if all(re < 0 for re in real_parts):
        stability = "Stable"
    else:
        stability = "Unstable"
    
        print(f"\nStability: {stability}")

When running the code I receive the error message "TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational". Kindly help me to check the source of this error.
Thank you.

Share the traceback.

If I am right, the all() function (inside # Check the stability) expects a list of booleans, but re < 0 is a symbolic inequality when re is a symbolic expression, and SymPy doesn’t know how to interpret that as a boolean. Use a simple cast to float could help. Like: if all(float(re) < 0 for re in real_parts):
